# I want to drop only one table when ever sailsjs lift

Tags: mongodb, sails.js

I want to migrate only one table to drop whenever sails lift I wanted to delete that table. How it is possible to do? Or is there any way to delete table after sails lift?

I already tried to add migrate : 'drop'    in that particular model but it won't work.

I am currently using sails 1.0 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way. 
[Sails Bootstrap](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-bootstrap)
This runs before sails lifted
I drop the table here.

> config/bootstrap.js

```
module.exports.bootstrap = async function() {
    await Users.destroy({});
};
```

Answer (score 1):

## Manually Delete

if you want to delete collection manually, you can use this command in shell.

`db.collection.drop()`

check this link for more detail [click here](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_drop.asp)

## Delete via Sails.js

to use low-level native code for mongodb

```
// Get access to the native MongoDB client via the default Sails datastore.
var db = sails.getDatastore().manager;

db.collection('users').drop()
```

find link here [link](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/tutorials/using-mongo-db#?lowlevel-mongodb-usage-advanced)

Comment: I want to drop a table only when sails lift.

Comment: you can use another mechanism, because when sails lift this process is under sails...
find this approach drop table when you app is started, when app loaded and load up first entry point then drop table.... because this process under our app.

Comment: I have found a way.

Answer (score 0):

In sails.js structure there is one file called bootstrap which located in config folder.

bootstrap file execute before sails server is lift.

so whatever you wan't to do before server lifting you can write code in this bootstrap file.

```
module.exports.bootstrap = function(callback) {
     Users.destroy({},(error,response)=>
     { 
        if(error) { console.log("error while deleting table"); }
        else { callback(); }
     });
};
```